# Nontrivial 'classical' examples of contracting differential transformations on compact Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. A differentiable map $f:M\to M$ is called contracting (self-made definition) if the linear map $D_x f:T_x M \to T_x M$ has the operator norm bounded by $1$ w.r.t. the norms on $T_x M$ induced by Riemannian metric on it for all $x\in M$.

The only examples that I am aware of are either isometries or constant maps. I wonder if there are any relatively nontrivial, natural, classical examples of contracting maps on compact Riemannian manifolds. (Please don't worry too much about the words "natural" and "classical" too much...)

Comment: I don't know if this matters to you, but, if $M$ is compact and if $f$ is contracting and not an isometry then $f$ is not surjective. This holds more generally if $M$ has finite volume.

Comment: Your definition is unclear: Do you require that $||D_x||\le 1$ for all points $x$ or just for one point? Regardless, I suggest you think about linear maps of the Euclidean $n$-space,  $f: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^n$, to expand your set of examples.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm sorry, I meant for all $x\in M$. Will correct it! Thanks!

Comment: Your definition requires that $x$ be a fixed point (for every $x$). Clearly, you do not intend that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the smooth map $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto (\operatorname{cos}(x_1), \operatorname{sin}(x_1),0)$ and the compact regular submanifold $S^2$ with induced Riemannian metric. Then $D_xf : T_x\mathbb{R}^3 \to T_{f(x)}\mathbb{R}^3$  has matrix
$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\operatorname{sin}(x_1)&0&0\\
\operatorname{cos}(x_1)&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ with $||D_xf|| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. The restriction $f : S^2 \to S^2$ is also smooth ($f(\mathbb{R}^3)\subset S^2$, $S^2$ is a embedded submanifold) and therefore $D_xf : T_xS^2 \to T_{f(x)}S^2$ has norm $\leq 1$ for all $x \in S^2$.

Comment: Interesting example, although it clearly collapses $S^2$  rather severely!

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you know an example which does not collapse the space so much?